# Elasticsearch cannot open log file: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, elasticsearch

#### The error

I installed Elasticsearch on CentOS using `rpm` and am encountering this error when I try to start it via `systemctl start elasticsearch`:

```
Feb 20 21:08:34 server.cberdata.org systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
Feb 20 21:08:34 server.cberdata.org elasticsearch[4226]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file /var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log due to Permission denied
Feb 20 21:08:51 server.cberdata.org systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Feb 20 21:08:51 server.cberdata.org systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Feb 20 21:08:51 server.cberdata.org systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

**Notably:** `Cannot open file /var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log due to Permission denied`

---

#### Permissions

Permissions for `/var`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root  4096 Feb 11 19:10 var
```

Permissions for `/var/log`:

```
drwxrwxr--  12 root  root   4096 Feb 20 21:00 log
```

Permissions for `/var/log/elasticsearch`:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 elasticsearch elasticsearch        4096 Feb 20 20:56 elasticsearch
```

Permissions for `/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log`
(which I manually created to see if that would help, but doing so had no effect on the error):

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 elasticsearch elasticsearch      0 Feb 20 20:56 gc.log
```

**Setting `/var/log` permissions to `drwxrwxrwx` appears to fix the problem**, but I'm hesitant to do that because it seems insecure and it results in these new errors:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: skipping "/var/log/exim_mainlog" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.
```

---

Am I correct that `systemctl` / `systemd` is running this service as the `elasticsearch` user? If it's doing that, how can the owner of the file and its directory, with apparent read/write/execute permissions, not have permission to open that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The directory `/var/log` has `774` permissions. As the execute bit isn't set, the elasticsearch user can't traverse the directory  to get the `elasticsearch` directory and the `gc.log` file contained therein.

Normally, the `/var/log` directory has `755` permissions or else no services or applications running as anyone other than root would be able to write to it.

You can fix it by using:

```
chmod 755 /var/log
```

You also don't need to have `777` permissions on the elasticsearch directory and the log file. The can use a variation of the above command to set the permissions:

```
chmod -R 755 /var/log/elasticsearch
```

Comment: That worked! I forgot that execute is needed for directory traversal. Thanks, Nasir!

Comment: @PhantomWatson You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could still access it, straight away, like this:

```
sudo nano /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I wasn't having trouble personally accessing the file with the user account I was logged in with, but rather with the `elasticsearch` user account being able to access it as part of a running service.